# Determining if a username is in a SQLite3 database using Python

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

So I'm new to programming, currently taking the HarvardX CS50 course.  So forgive my noob-level understanding of things.

Right now I'm working on a registration page for a website.  User needs to enter a username and password, then confirm their password.  The system should then check to make sure that username is not already in use.  This is where my problem lies I believe:

```
# Checks to see if username exists already, if so return apology
            usernamecheck = db.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE username = :username", username)
    
           if usernamecheck != 0:
                return apology("Username already exists.")
```

I've been sitting with this for days and can't crack it.  Would greatly appreciate someone telling me how to fix this.

Code:

```py
@app.route("/register", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def register():
    """Register user"""

    if request.method == "GET":
        return render_template("register.html")
    else:
        # Take input for username
        username = request.form.get("username")

        #If username is blank return apology
        if not username:
            return apology("You must enter a username.")

        # Checks to see if username exists already, if so return apology
        usernamecheck = db.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE username = :username", username)

       if usernamecheck != 0:
            return apology("Username already exists.")

        # Take input for password
        password = request.form.get("password")

        # if password is blank, return apology
        if not password:
            return apology("You must enter a password.")

        # Take input for confirmation
        confirmation = request.form.get("confirmation")

        # if confirmation is blank, return apology
        if not confirmation:
            return apology("You must confirm your password.")

        # if password and confirmation don't match, return apology
        if password != confirmation:
            return apology("Your password confirmation does not match the password.")

        # hash the password with generate_password_hash
        pwhash = generate_password_hash(request.form.get("password"))

        # insert the username and hash into the users table
        sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, hash) VALUES (':username', '1234')"
      # sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, pwhash VALUES ('" + username + "', '" + pwhash + "'), username = '" + username + "', pwhash = '" + pwhash + "'"
        print(sql)
        db.execute(sql)
        return redirect("/")
```

Here's everything terminal shows for the error:

```
ERROR:application:Exception on /register [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2446, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1951, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1949, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1935, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/ubuntu/finance/application.py", line 160, in register
    usernamecheck = db.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE username = :username", username)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cs50/sql.py", line 21, in decorator
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cs50/sql.py", line 219, in execute
    raise RuntimeError("missing value for placeholder (:{})".format(name))
RuntimeError: missing value for placeholder (:username)
INFO:werkzeug:192.168.83.137 - - [27/Jun/2020 02:51:17] "POST /register HTTP/1.0" 500 -
INFO:werkzeug:192.168.83.137 - - [27/Jun/2020 02:51:17] "GET /static/styles.css HTTP/1.0" 200 -
```

Edit: I've been through the Python documentation, I see their examples, but trying to implement it doesn't work for some reason.  I've been at this for days and I'm getting super frustrated.  Hoping someone can provide not just the solution but also explain it in a relatively easy to understand way?

Comment: The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute) show a rather clear example. You need a dictionary for the parameter(s). Also see the docs how to retrieve the count you requested from the database.

Comment: @MichaelButscher While I appreciate the response, I've been through the docs several times now and unfortunately I'm not at a point where I really understand what it's saying (or don't know how to interpret it to solve this particular problem) because when I attempt to replicate their examples in my code it doesn't work.  I'm hoping someone can show me the solution and explain why it's that way so that I can easily understand, rather than yet again banging my head against a wall trying to understand the documentation.

Comment: The particular line should be `db.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE username = :username", {"username": username})`. You should know what a dictionary is and means. If not, it makes not much sense to work with advanced things like databases or flask. Be also aware that `execute` doesn't return anything meaningful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is almost right. All you need to provide the value of `username` as shown below.

```
usernamecheck = db.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE username = :username", username=username)
```

Notice there is no space between the the `=` sign.

Comment: That worked as far as getting me past my internal server error!  Thank you!  Now follow up question if you don't mind.  It's still returning an error that the username already exists even though it doesn't.  My powers of deduction tell me it would be an issue somewhere here:
if usernamecheck != 0:
            return apology("Username already exists.", 403)

I printed usernamecheck and it prints just [], which to me means 0, so not sure why it's thinking it exists.  Any ideas on that?

Comment: I'm glad it worked. And I do not mind at all answering even more questions. So, if you fire up the python terminal or idle and `print([ ] == 0)` you will get `True` and that's why your code outputs `"Username already exists"`. Change your condition to `if len(usernamecheck) > 0  :` instead